# Encontrar en un diccionario la clave más baja y el valor más alto en Python

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo Python y quiero consultar sobre un ejercicio.

Enunciado:

> Dado un array en el que se contabilizan los avistajes de distintos
> tipos de pájaros, identificados por medio de un ID, determinar qué
> tipo de pájaro fue visto con mayor frecuencia. Si más de un tipo de
> pájaro coinciden con la mayor cantidad de avistajes, devolver el ID de
> menor valor. Ejemplo: Arr = [1,1,2,2,3] Se solicita completar la
> función pajarosMigratorios(), asumiendo que se reciben 2 parámetros
> Parámetros de entrada
>
> - n: cantidad de pájaros vistos
> - int arr[n]: tipos de pájaros vistos Parámetros de salida
> - int: el type ID más bajo de los pájaros más vistos

**Input Format**
La primera línea contiene un integer, n, el tamaño de arr.
La segunda línea describe arr como una lista de n números separados por espacio, representando cada uno a un tipo de pájaro visto.

```
Ejemplo Input #1
n= 6arr = 1 4 4 4 5 3
Ejemplo Output #1
4

Ejemplo Input #2
n= 11arr= 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 3 4
Ejemplo Output #2
3
```

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora, no se como hacer para que muestre la clave más baja con el valor más alto.

```
import collections
def pajarosMigratorios (cant,lista):
    frecuencia={}
    frecuencia=collections.Counter(lista)
    clavefinal=0
    valorfinal=0
    for item1 in frecuencia.keys():
      clave1=item1
      valor1=frecuencia[item1]
      
      for item2 in frecuencia.keys():
        clave2=item2
        valor2=frecuencia[item2]
        
     
      if (clave1<clave2) and ((valor1==valor2)or(valor1>valor2)):
          clavefinal=clave1
          valorfinal=valor1
          
        
    print(clavefinal,":",valorfinal)
pajaros = [1,1,2,2,3]

pajarosMigratorios(5,pajaros)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cosa es mucho más sencilla de lo que crees, todo se resume a unas cuantas líneas de código.
Una vez ya tengamos el objeto `Counter` debemos de ordenar ese objeto según el valor de las veces que se repite cada elemento, eso lo hacemos con la función `sorted` que nos permite ordenar un iterable y gracias al parámetro `key` que nos permite decir en base a que queremos que se ordene.

```py
from collections import Counter

def pajarosMigratorios (cant,lista):
    frecuency = Counter(lista)
    #con .items() obtienes una tupla (key, value) y ordenamos según el value
    return sorted(frecuency.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0] #retornamos el primer elemento

pajaros = [1,1,2,2,3]
clave,valor = pajarosMigratorios(5,pajaros)
print(f"{clave}: {valor}")
```

En este caso obtenemos como resultado:

```
1: 2
```

lo que nos indica que el elemento `1` se ha repetido más veces, en este caso 2 veces.

Comment: No hace faltar ordenar. El método `Counter.most_common()` ya ordena el contador de mayor a menor frecuencia.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tu respuesta me sirvió